# Wrong value showing in antd

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have antd form

```
<Form.Item label="Sub Ref" name="SubRefID"  rules={[{ required: true, message: 'Please input!' }]}>
                      {IsEdit ? <Select size="small" style={{ width: '100%' }} dropdownMatchSelectWidth={false}
                      value={PatientInfo.SubRefName}
                        showSearch
                        
                        filterOption={(input, option) =>
                          option.children.toLowerCase().indexOf(input.toLowerCase()) >= 0
                        }
                      >
                        {SubRef.map((d) => <Select.Option value={d.SubRefID}>{d.Name}</Select.Option>)}
                      </Select> : <div className="label" title={'SubRef By: ' + PatientInfo.SubRefName}>{PatientInfo.SubRefName}</div>}
                    </Form.Item>
```

I want to show subRefName in edit. In certain condition subrefId has value and subrefName has no value that time also I want to print empty string. Now the subrefID is printing instead of subRefName.